# gems/plugins for affiliate system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Do you remember any gems/plugins out there to support an affiliate (referral, partner) like system?

e.g the 37signals [affiliate program](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1063-launch-announcing-the-new-37signals-affiliate-program-with-recurring-income)

Any help/links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/substruct/wiki/HelpAffiliates

Is an open-source Rails e-commerce CMS that apparently supports an affiliate program out of the box. I'm considering it for an upcoming project, however I have no experience with it yet.

Comment: Thanks! this looks promising, by the way I ended up writing my own affiliates system.

Comment: Hi Juan I'm looking for a rails 3 aff. solution at this moment. Got any tips how'd you start with your affiliate system?

Comment: @Ayrton, Hey I'm sorry for the delay, well I ended up writing the whole system by myself, it's not a big deal, I created an `Affiliation` model that acts as join table for `affiliate` and `referred` (https://gist.github.com/c3446da1918e5bb07753) and then I added some logic on the controllers, I could share with you the code, just let me know if you're still working on this!

Comment: @jpemberthy I'm going to start with this very soon. I would be pleased if you could share the code

Comment: This code could give you some ideas of how to implement this, https://gist.github.com/083154b384a27d43f141